# To move Folder from one location to another in WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: image, file, sftp, wso2-enterprise-integrator, vfs

I have developed API which is used to download images to local path with Specific Folder name which works fine. My requirement here is **to move folder with Files(Images) to SFTP Location**. Nothing happened, File resides in the same Input path. Can anyone please help me?

**Download Folder Name:** Stock001 which has image File(.jpg )

[image: Download Folder which has imageFile]

Proxy Code:

VFS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SFTP_Proxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS:" value="---------SFTP Proxy Invoked-------------------"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence/>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.PollInterval">15</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileURI">file:///D:/Test/CarSalesStockImages/Input/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ContentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterProcess">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterFailure">file:///D:/Test/CarSalesStockImages/Failed/</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.ActionAfterFailure">MOVE</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.FileNamePattern">.*.*</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.vfs.MoveAfterProcess">vfs:sftp://test-dev:U46A0hTf2vhjytqq@3.109.0.212/wso2/QRSagProcess/VB/CarSalesStockImages</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

**FileConnetor:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="SFTP_Proxy"
       startOnLoad="true"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       transports="http,https">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS:" value="---------SFTP Proxy Invoked-------------------"/>
         </log>
         <fileconnector.copy>
            <source>file:///D:/Test/CarSalesStockImages/Input/</source>
            <destination>sftp://test-dev:pwd@ipaddress/wso2/QRSagProcess/VB/CarSalesStockImages/</destination>
         </fileconnector.copy>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS:" value="---------File Copied-------------------"/>
         </log>
         <fileconnector.delete>
            <source>file:///D:/Test/CarSalesStockImages/Input/</source>
            <setUserDirIsRoot>true</setUserDirIsRoot>
         </fileconnector.delete>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS:"
                      value="---------File Deleted from Source-------------------"/>
         </log>
         <fileconnector.create>
            <source>file:///D:/Test/CarSalesStockImages/Input/</source>
         </fileconnector.create>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence/>
      <faultSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="STATUS:"
                      value="------------faultSequence Invoked----------------"/>
         </log>
         <log level="full"/>
      </faultSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Error:

```
[2020-05-29 10:59:23,145] [] ERROR - VFSTransportListener Error resolving directory to move after processing : sftp://qrs-dev":***@"3.109.0.212/wso2/QRSagProcess/VB/CarSalesStockI
ages/
org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "sftp://test-dev:***@3.109.0.212/".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:108)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.getFileSystem(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:155)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:119)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.findFile(AbstractOriginatingFileProvider.java:88)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:747)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.impl.DefaultFileSystemManager.resolveFile(DefaultFileSystemManager.java:626)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.moveOrDeleteAfterProcessing(VFSTransportListener.java:662)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.scanFileOrDirectory(VFSTransportListener.java:499)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:188)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.vfs.VFSTransportListener.poll(VFSTransportListener.java:134)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.AbstractPollingTransportListener$1$1.run(AbstractPollingTransportListener.java:67)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs2.FileSystemException: Could not connect to SFTP server at "3.105.0.247".
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:268)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpFileProvider.doCreateFileSystem(SftpFileProvider.java:97)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:512)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
        at org.apache.commons.vfs2.provider.sftp.SftpClientFactory.createConnection(SftpClientFactory.java:264)
        ... 15 more
[2020-05-29 10:59:23,150] [] ERROR - VFSTransportListener File object 'file:///D:/Test/CarSalesStockImages/Input/Test.txt'cloud not be moved, will remain in "locked" state
```

Comment: It seems that ESB server is unable to connect to the sftp server. Can you connect to the same sftp server from the ESB instance from an external ftp client

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna,
Thanks for ur reply.I can able to connect through putty/ Filezilla by using same credentials with key file. let me know if u have any other way to achieve this.

Comment: Are you using an SFTP key file to connect to the FTP server with the external client? In that case, you should use the same mechanism with the ESB server. You can provide the private key with the transport.vfs.SFTPIdentities parameter.

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna,
Yes u r right, already tried with SFTPIdentities and SFTPIdentityPassPhrase in VFS. unfortunately not able to connect with sftp. and my goal is to move Folders, not Files. so i chose FileConnector. kindly have a look once above FileConnetor code and pls let me know if anything is wrong in above. Thanks for sharing useful information

Comment: Hi @ShanakaPremarathna,
Added to above, there is no other option to include KeyFile in FileConnectors also. Can u pls let me know if anything is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be able to verify the syntax of the destination? A sample I came across this: http://mrmalakasilva.blogspot.com/2016/07/automating-file-processing-with-wso2.html
Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Buddima,
Thanks for your information, Documentation shows different kind of syntax "https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-delete"  can u duggest me exact syntax to connect with sftp server? i followed this for sftp "https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Working+with+the+File+Connector#WorkingwiththeFileConnector-create"